# Python equivalent of Java abstract classes?

Tags: java, python, abstract-class, abstraction

I have some experience coding in Java, but right now I find myself in a situation where I am forced to code in Python. What I am trying to do is develop a class structure extending from an abstract class Document down into multiple document types that will retrieve different information from a database depending on their type. Since there are probably at least a hundred different document types, I feel using abstraction to offload as much code as possible further up the structure is my best option.

In Java, I would write something like this:

```
public abstract class Document(){
    private String department
    private String date
    ...
    public Document(){
    ...}
    public abstract String writeDescription(){
    ...}
}
```

In Python, I'm not quite sure what my best option to do something like this is. Right now, the two major possibilities I have seen are to use the abc plugin (https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), or to simply use basic Python inheritance structures, like this: [Abstraction in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163197/abstraction-in-python)

Can I accomplish what I need without this abc plugin, or is it going to be necessary to do what I want?

Comment: Do you really need an ABC with a dynamically typed language like Python? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type#Use_of_abstract_types.

Comment: @Fred Larson Perhaps this is just rigid Java instincts that I have, but I want to ensure that specific methods are written - the `writeDescription` one for example. But since there are going to be many ways to do this method depending on document type. I suppose a generic method that gets overridden/updated when necessary could work, but this was the first structure that made sense to me.

Comment: If you want `writeDescription` implemented in sub-classes, it would be conventional to have the super-class [`raise NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError) for that method.

Comment: What's wrong with the `abc` module? That's *the* way to achieve abstract classes.

Comment: @user1598518 You're on the right track there, treat your parent class like a Java 8 interface with some or every method having defaults. (Which can be done with the `abc` module for more clarity, in fact.)

Comment: @delnan there's nothing _wrong_ with it, it's just that I don't fully understand it, and so I'm wondering if I can circumvent it and still do what I want. My project is on a bit of a timeline, so academic interest isn't my only motivation; I would love to understand it as I become more Python fluent

Comment: @user1598518 Then "How do I use ABCs?" would be a more effective question. But there's nothing strange or hard about them anyway. For Java-style abstract classes (`abc` can do more but you don't have to use it), you only need to add `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` and throw a decorator at the abstract methods: `abstract int x(float y) {}` becomes `@abstractmetod def x(y): pass`. You probably could have learned this in the ten minutes it took to write this question, read the reactions, and comment if you bothered to read an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of using such a rigid structure in Java is that you have compile time checking that subclasses fulfils the contract their ABC defines.  You can still use inheritance and polymorphism in python, but you don't get any static checking for free.

What I would do is define an ABC in vanilla python with method stubs for functionality you want all documents to support.

```
class Document(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # do stuff

    def getDescription(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("getDescription() in Document is not implemented")

class DocumentImpl(Document)
    def __init__(self):
        super(DocumentImpl, self).__init__()

    def getDescription(self):
        return "this is a document impl"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for, I believe!